# Getting Error Running react-native run-ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactjs, react-native

I am new to react-native when I init a project and then run

> react-native run-ios

I get this error

```
** BUILD FAILED **

Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AwesomeProject.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AwesomeProject.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
```

> node -v 6.5.0
>
> react-native-cli: 1.0.0
>
> react-native: 0.32.1
>
> xcode 8 beta 5

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your versions are too new or not up to date?

my run-ios works

node -v
v6.0.0

react-native -v
react-native-cli: 0.2.0

Did you trying running your project directly in xcode? Might give you more clues.

Comment: When i try to build it using xcode I get two errors in RCTWebSocket 
hello/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/WebSocket/RCTSRWebSocket.m:494:3: Ignoring return value of function declared with warn_unused_result attribute
/hello/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/WebSocket/RCTSRWebSocket.m:1334:5: Ignoring return value of function declared with warn_unused_result attribute

Comment: were you able to solve it @MuhammadMohsinTariq
Even I have the same issue and I dunno how to solve it